# Load iFrame at Margin: -9999px; Move iFrame Margin to +20px after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, function, iframe, delay, wait

As the title says, I want to load an iFrame out of the visible window, at margin:-9999px; and then move it into the visible window after a 5 second delay.

This is because I am performing a function on the iFrame and don't want users to see it until that function is complete.

The code I am running is this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){jQuery(".Remover").find("p, ul").remove()});
          jQuery(window).load(function(){jQuery(".footnote").find("*").remove()});
```

If I can tell the browser not to show the result until the above is complete that would also be acceptable.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Give your iframe visibility hidden (via css or explicit styling):

```
iframe {visibility: hidden;}
```

then after your load is complete inside the frame you can set it to visible:

```
$(window.frameElement).css("visibility", "visible");
```